# "df -h" and "fdisk -l" in amazon server

Tags: disk-usage, fdisk, df

When you do a `df -h` you can see:

```
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1 7 . 9G 1.7G 6.2G 22% /
```

But, when you do `fdisk -l` you see:

```
Disk /dev/xvda1: 26.8 GB, 26843545600 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3263 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

Can someone help?

Comment: welcome to Stack Exchange! I've flagged your question as "unclear what you're asking" because, well, it's unclear. please edit your question using the edit link (right below the tags) and clarify what you want us to help with. thanks!

Comment: @strugee you can embed the edit link in a comment by writing `[edit]` (without the inverted commas), it looks like this: [edit].

Answer (score 2):

The two programs give different information (try `man fdisk` and `man df`). `fdisk` will show you the available partitions of the disk (those are the lines that come after the output you have posted) and `df` will show the usage of **mounted** partitions.

If that is the entirety of the `df -h` output, it looks like you only have one partition mounted, `/dev/xvda1` which is 7.9G. Based on the output you posted, you probably ran `fdisk -l /dev/xvda1` not `fdisk -l`. This should also have returned an error:

```
Disk /dev/xvda1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

That's because `fdisk` should be run on disks, not partitions. Try `fdisk -l /dev/xvda` (without the partition number) or simply `fdisk -l`. That should show you the full partition table of all your disks. One of these partitions will be `xvda1` and will be 7.9G in size. When you run `fdsik` on a partition, it reports the size of the entire disk (26.8 GB in your case), not the size of the partition you gave it as input.